# Jquery add hyperlink to a string value

Tags: jquery

I am writing this code in jquery . var name= " this is a sample text and click here to visit google.com " . Now I want to add a hyperlink to the word " click here " only. eg of the link has to be google.com. and the variable name will be displayed on the front end .

Answer (score 0):

You don't need jQuery for a simple hyperlink. Just use the `<a>` tag from HTML.

```
<a href="www.google.com">This is a sample text and click here to visit google.com </a>
```

Comment: No I am writing the entire code in Jquery .  I have no elements in the <body> . I am displaying the name variable with some strings in it and , I was wondering if I could add a hyperlink there...

Comment: But how do you want to show the text? For this you need HTML.